# Octave: How to create a legend for grouped bar graphs?

Tags: octave

I'm using Octaves "bar" command to plot a grouped bar graph based on data loded from a matrix stored in an external file. A similar plot based on random data can be created using this command:

```
bar(rand(4, 6));
```

I'd like to create a legend explaning the 6 bar colors occurring in each group instead of a legend for the 4 bar groups themselves. Executing the command

```
legend({"Probe 1", "Probe 2", "Probe 3", "Probe 4", "Probe 5", "Probe 6"});
```

creates the legend labels but does not assign the bar colors. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Octave `legend` documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/legend.html), specifically examples 18 and 19, you should get what you are looking for with either `legend('Probe 1', 'Probe 2', ...);` or with `legend({'Probe 1', 'Probe 2', ...});`. Maybe try changing your quotations to single-quotes.

You can also get a handle to your bar graph with:

```
b = bar(rand(4, 6));
```

And then plot the legend with color boxes with:

```
legend(b, 'probe 1', 'probe 2', ...);
```

[image: MATLAB result]

**Edit:** I tested each of the above methods and they all produced the legend that I believe you are looking for. The result looked slightly different than the figure here (made with MATLAB), but functionally the same. Oddly enough, so did your syntax (with double quotes instead of single). Are you plotting the figure in X11? Or are you plotting anything on top of the bar chart before generating the legend? Passing the handle to the bar chart should solve the latter case.